# optparse-applicative: displaying help for programs invoked with no arguments

Tags: haskell, command-line-arguments, applicative

I'm using `optparse-applicative` version 0.7.0.2.

I want to write a parser that takes some mandatory options, but that when invoked with no options it shows *both* usage and help, as opposed to just usage (that is, I want the invocation with no options to behave as the invocation with `--help`).

I can't figure out how to do so, [even if the documentation says it is possible](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.7.0.2):

> The hello option in this example is mandatory (since it doesn't have a
>   default value), so running the program without any argument will
>   display a help text

Is there a working example of this? The one in the main documentation doesn't work for me (it prints  usage only.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, it looks like the only way to do this is to create your own version of `customExecParser` from the [Options.Applicative.Extra module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.7.0.2/docs/src/Options-Applicative-Extra.html#customExecParser). There is [an open issue](https://github.com/pcapriotti/optparse-applicative/issues/57#issuecomment-28879564) to make this simpler.

Something like this should be pretty close to what you're looking for:

```
import Options.Applicative
import Options.Applicative.Help as AH
import Options.Applicative.Types as AT
import System.Environment (getArgs, getProgName)
import System.Exit (exitWith, ExitCode(..))
import System.IO (hPutStr, stderr)

execParserWithHelp :: ParserPrefs -> ParserInfo a -> IO a
execParserWithHelp pprefs pinfo = do
  args <- getArgs
  case execParserPure pprefs pinfo args of
    Right a -> return a
    Left failure -> do
      progn <- getProgName
      msg <- AT.errMessage failure progn
      let extra = if null args
                  then AH.parserHelpText pprefs pinfo
                  else ""
      let c = errExitCode failure
      case c of
        ExitSuccess -> putStr (msg ++ extra)
        _           -> hPutStr stderr (msg ++ extra)
      exitWith c

main :: IO ()
main = execParserWithHelp (prefs idm) opts >>= run

opts :: ParserInfo Command
opts = info (commands <**> helper) idm

run :: Command -> IO ()
run = ...
```

This is basically just `customExecParser` with a small block that checks if the args are empty. If they are, it displays the parser help.

Comment: This commit may have added an easier way to do the above: https://github.com/pcapriotti/optparse-applicative/commit/bab98fe8ee95635a0befca6ad9365be7d31b0541

Answer (score 11):

Reviving an old topic, but I've added the `showHelpOnEmpty` pref for this so it's now simple. Given a parser `p :: ParserInfo a`

```
run :: IO a
run = customExecParser (prefs showHelpOnEmpty) p
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to print the `--help` output on *all* errors,
*including* when the program is run with no arguments, then replace
calls to `execParser` with calls to `showHelpOnErrorExecParser`,
defined by

```
-- | A version of 'execParser' which shows full help on error.                
--                                                                            
-- The regular 'execParser' only prints usage on error, which doesn't         
-- include the options, subcommands, or mention of the help switch            
-- @--help@.                                                                  
showHelpOnErrorExecParser :: ParserInfo a -> IO a
showHelpOnErrorExecParser = customExecParser (prefs showHelpOnError)
```

Based on [comment](https://github.com/pcapriotti/optparse-applicative/issues/57#issuecomment-28777909) on issue linked in accepted answer.